# Godus, Building abodes with wheat?

Tags: godus

I didn't read the screen tips at the time, but why do you all of a sudden have to build houses with wheat when you didn't have to before, can you return to building abodes without wheat since it takes ages to make wheat and only produces a few amount?

Answer (score 1):

Nope you cannot.  If you have the newest update 50.5% complete.  You will be able to get more wheat from your farms every 60 or 90 minutes plus or minus nearby buffs.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said, there is no way. 
The first appereance of wheat almost stoped my economy completely due I had not been able to build houses in hours.

This is getting better soon, If you follow these tips:

1. build fields, the more the better.
   You already built a Farm, does it have more than one field?
   If not, make room for more! Klick on the farm to see how many farmers could live in there. Every farmer can work on his own field.
2. larger fields, larger crops.
   Level 1 fields only generate 1 wheat, level 2 fields 2 wheat, level 3 fields 4 wheat and so on (1,2,4,8..). So bigger fields are better than more fields (still you should have as many as possible). All fields grow at the same speed.
3. It's all about size.
   2 side story farms are not what you want. They should house as many farmers as possible, so better use the largest houses for your farm.

I've got the game just 3 days ago (mobile version, seems the desktop version is faster) and got ~1200 settlers. Doing fine with 5 Farms with 4-5 fields each. Number of farms is good, but more essential is the size of the farm itself, and the size of its fields.

One farm with 5 level 3 fields is better than 4 farms with 5 level 1 fields.